# Delphi XE6 android with estimote beacon convertion

Tags: android, delphi

I am stuck in conversion of Java code to Delphi. I have converted all estimote beacon sdk and also created classes.dex. I can call beacon method. But some part of java code of the estimote beacon example can't be converted to delphi. I got no idea how to do that. Below is java code which I need to convert in Delphi XE6:

```java
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
  @Override
  public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
    // Note that results are not delivered on UI thread.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Note that beacons reported here are already sorted by estimated
        // distance between device and beacon.
        getActionBar().setSubtitle("Found beacons: " + beacons.size());
        adapter.replaceWith(beacons);
      }
    });
  }
});

  private void connectToService() {
    getActionBar().setSubtitle("Scanning...");
    adapter.replaceWith(Collections.<Beacon>emptyList());
    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onServiceReady() {
        try {
          beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
          Toast.makeText(ListBeaconsActivity.this, "Cannot start ranging, something terrible happened",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging", e);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

For servicereadycallback beacon interface I made delphi class as following:

```pascal
  TBeaconServiceRead = class(TJavaLocal, JBeaconManager_ServiceReadyCallback)
  private
    fParent: TForm4;
  public
    constructor Create(parent: TForm4);
    function equals(o: JObject): boolean; cdecl;
    function getClass: Jlang_Class; cdecl;
    function hashCode: Integer; cdecl;
    procedure notify; cdecl;
    procedure notifyAll; cdecl;
    function toString: JString; cdecl;
    procedure wait; overload; cdecl;
    procedure wait(millis: Int64); overload; cdecl;
    procedure wait(millis: Int64; nanos: Integer); overload; cdecl;
    procedure onServiceReady; cdecl;
  end;
```

When I try to call beaconmanager.connect(TBeaconServiceRead.Create(self)), I got error as following:
java.lang.NullPointerExceptio:callback can not be null.
How to overcome the exception? Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is my onServiceReady method:

```
procedure TBeaconServiceRead.onServiceReady;
var
  fregion: JRegion;
begin
  CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(
    procedure
    begin
      fregion := TJRegion.JavaClass.init
        (StringToJString('rid'), nil, nil, nil);
      bm.startRanging(fregion);
      TForm4(fParent).Memo1.Lines.Add('beacon manager connect: ' + JStringToString(fregion.getProximityUUID));
    end);
end;
```

Comment: I do not have knowledge about the service, though my first question and suggestion is that could you separate Create method and Connect methods from each other on different lines, and put a debug message between them like that: TBeaconServiceRead bsr = TBeaconServiceRead.Create(self); writeln("Debug 1"); beaconmanager.connect( bsr );

Comment: According to the examples on this link (http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/BeaconManager.html), it implements the ServiceReadyCallback method.

Comment: This is what I did also, First create TBeaconServiceRead instance and then execute beaconmanager.connect( bsr ); callback is required which I am missing.